# How to create drag behaviour for overlapping SVG elements in React

Tags: reactjs, svg

*Problem illustrated in* https://codesandbox.io/s/dragging-overlapping-svgs-1jd5m

I would like to do something quite simple: implement drag behaviour in my SVG elements in my React App. So my initial thoughts were to capture start and stop dragging by `onMouseDown` and `onMouseUp` events, and to implement the updating in the `onMouseMove` event. In principle, like so:

```
  <circle
    ...
    onMouseDown={() => startDrag()}
    onMouseUp={() => endDrag()}
    onMouseMove={event => dragging && drag(event)}
  />
```

In my React class `Circ` I implemented the behaviours like so:

```
const Circ = ({ cx, cy, r, fill, stroke }) => {
  const [draggingPosition, setDraggingPosition] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });

  const startDrag = () => {
    setDragging(true);
  };
  const endDrag = () => {
    setDragging(false);
  };
  const drag = event => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    setDraggingPosition({
      x: draggingPosition.x + event.movementX,
      y: draggingPosition.y + event.movementY
    });
  };
  ...
}
```

Well, that basically worked. But now when my SVG contains several *overlapping* elements, it starts to break down:

```
const SVG = () => (
  <svg width={617} height={316} viewBox="0 0 400 400">
    <g>
      <Circ cx={108} cy={108} r="100" fill="#0ff" stroke="#000" />
      <Circ cx={180} cy={209} r="100" fill="#ff0" stroke="#000" />
      <Circ cx={220} cy={109} r="100" fill="#f0f" stroke="#000" />
    </g>
  </svg>
);
```

When I drag the blue circle, its behaviour is fine until an overlapping circle captures the mouse event and my dragging stops.

[image: Drag behaviour is fine until a higher element captures the mouse event]

So my question is: how do I make sure that once I start dragging, the mouse event is restricted to only that current element? Ideally, also when there are other elements in the editor (`Rect`, `G`, etc...) that my `Circ` class does not necessarily know about?

Comment: Problem is caused by `onMouseMove` which is triggered by other SVGs. Suggestion / hint: keep information on focused circle and in `drag` function check if it's beeing triggered by focused one.

Comment: Set all the other elements to be pointer-events: none during the drag.

Comment: Thanks @RobertLongson, that's a good point. That would mean globally registering a 'dragging' variable and passing it on to every single child, right? I was hoping for a solution that could be restricted to the object itself.

Comment: I'd do it by modifying a css class or creating some css like * { pointer-events: none }  and applying that to the page together with an override for the current element.

Comment: Ah, that's good sneaky way of dealing with the global variable!

Answer (score 0):

I am now solving it with registering *dragging* at the global level and a 
`pointerEvents={ globalDragging ? "none" : "auto"}`
on all my elements. I'm not really happy with this solution, so I'm still happy to hear alternatives.